# aggregated/stored fields and asynchronous jobs

Tags: java, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.2

I have an `Coupon` entity class stored in DB which has stages represented as enum.

Something like this:

```
enum CouponStatus {
        CREATED,
        PUBLISHED,
        STARTED,
        FINISHED,
        RESULTSARRIVED,
        POINTSASSIGNED,
        MONEYPAID,
        CLOSED
}
```

It also has a @ManyToMany list of `Game` entities each of which has a `Date` field. And the status of the `Coupon` should change based on the **date** of containing **games**.

To give you the idea:

- The initial status is CREATED.
- Two weeks before the date of the earliest game status becomes
  PUBLISHED.
- 5 minutes before the date of the earliest status becomes STARTED.
- Three hours after the start of the latest game status is FINISHED.
- When the results of all games will be inserted into the other table
  the status becomes RESULTSARRIVED.
- and so on...

Based on the status I do different things:

- Show a coupon in the list of coupons only if status is PUBLISHED.
- Stop showing and stop accepting bets when the status is STARTED.
- Send request for results to external system when status if FINISHED.

I see 3 possibilities:

1. Do not use a status field at all. Means do my different things not based on the status, but based directly on the date fields of the games. In this way I need to fetch games of the coupon each time I show a list of coupon to the user.
2. Have a job running each minute which fetches games and changes the status.
3. Have a job running and rescheduled dynamically each time based on the expected next status change based on the date of the games.

I'm obviously not the first one to have a problem of this kind.
Are there any other approaches? What are the best practices for such things?

Comment: Side note: I personally don't like using enum with entities as those are represented by integers on the DB. This makes it more difficult to map code to value and to maintain as if you change your statuses (remove or change ordering) you have to migrate the DB values.

Comment: You are right about maintenance, but without @EnumValue("1"), @EnumValue("2"), ... Play represents enums as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like #2 is probably good enough.  A combination of #2 and #3 might be handy if you want the 5 minutes to be exact.

Another approach might be to manage the state in memory, for example using Akka, and synchronise the state to and from a database.  You would have one actor per Coupon, and these could be distributed over a large Akka cluster if you needed to scale beyond what will fit in the memory of one machine.  Using this approach, each actor would schedule when the next status change happens, and manage that itself.  You could also have your incoming requests, rather than going to the database, go to Akka.  It all depends on your use case.

Comment: In the approach with Akka should I have dedicated machines to manage the state and other dedicated machines to render the website itself? And these different servers are communicating via DB?

Comment: It really depends on your needs. They can communicate via Akka clustering/remoting.